# Javascript : Adding Key Value pair literal giving undefined result

Tags: javascript, jquery

it works on my last test but now its giving me hard time.. basically i have this code :

```
    var myOBJ = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < myitems.length; i++) {

    myOBJ[i].itemtype = myitems.type;
    myOBJ[i].name = myitems.name;

   }
```

inside `myitems` is a data that I need to rewrite to another `object` for some reason. but I'm stock with the error im having

```
Error: myOBJ[i] is undefined
```

could anyone tell my what im missing?

Comment: What is the structure of `myitems`?

Comment: you have to debug the code or print console what myOBJ will return

Comment: Knowing what's inside `myitems` (at least its structure) would probably help.

Comment: no problem with myitems...i receive its value, @dfsq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to intiliase an object inside every element you are trying to create, so basically do this:

```
var myOBJ = {};
for (var i = 0; i < myitems.length; i++) {
    // Create a new object here.
    myOBJ[i] = {};
    myOBJ[i].itemtype = myitems.type;
    myOBJ[i].name = myitems.name;
}
```

And since you are working numerically anyway, it might be better to create `myOBJ` as a numerical array:

```
var myOBJ = [];
```

Now I don't know how your `myitems` object works, but you can't actually iterate over it numerically if it contains two keys called `name` and `type`, as its an object so it does not have a `length` property. So you might get an error there. Assuming its actually an array with nested objects that contain `type` and `name` you can easily iterate over it an use `push()` to add an `object literal` to your array, like this:

```
var myOBJ = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myitems.length; i++) {
    // Create and push new object here.
    myOBJ.push({
        itemtype : myitems[i].type,
        name     : myitems[i]. name
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access an object literal by index, you must access it by **key**.

If `myOBJ` were an array, then you could access it by index. Or, if `myOBJ` had keys that were numbers, your code would work.

You can make each key a number pretty easily, and then be able to access each object by sort of a pseudo index, if you instantiate each object first.

```
myOBJ[i] = {};
```

This will output something like:

```
{
    1: {};
    //etc.
}
```

But why not simply make `myOBJ` an array?

Comment: Actually, you could use it in the same way as an `array`, it just doesnt have a length property (so `{0:"zero",1:"one",2:"two"}` is a functional equivalent to `["zero","one","two"]` bar the length property and the fact that its not sorted numerically (so it could be `{1:"one", 0:"zero", 2:"two"}`))

Comment: @somethinghere yes you're right, it is functionally equivalent, but the distinction here is that the numbers in the object are keys, even if you can make them act like indexes.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to copy values from `myitems` to another object in `myOBJ`, I suggest you change `myOBJ` to an `Array`, create a temp object inside loop and add that temp object to your myOBJ array

```
   var myOBJ = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < myitems.length; i++) {
    var item = myitems[i];
    var temp = {
      'itemtype' : item.type,
      'name' : item.name
    };
    myOBJ[i] = temp; // (or) myOBJ.push(temp);
   }
```

You can even retain `myOBJ = {}` but then again it will be just an object with each property being a `Number` which is semantically identical to an Array, so use an Array instead.

Comment: Glad to be of help but what I did is nothing creative, it's just the casual way of doing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your individual elements of `myOBJ` are initially undefined.

You must either create a new object to contain the properties:

```
myOBJ[i] = {};
myOBJ[i].itemtype = myitems.type;
myOBJ[i].name = myitems.name
```

or, perhaps more efficiently, just initialise it with an object literal:

```
myOBJ[i] = {
    itemtype: myitems.type,
    name: myitems.name
};
```

Since you only appear to be using numeric indices you should also consider using an array `[]` instead of an object `{}` for the variable `myOBJ`.